# segmentation fault while reindexing catalogsearch_fulltext in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, reindex, cli

I am trying to reindex all indexes using CLI which results segmetation fault. I am using magento2 version 2.0.8 and previously using 2.0.7 but later updated to 2.0.8. I am getting error in both version. My shop have about 200000 products.

**memory_limit is**

- 4096M Local Value in magento directory
- 512M Master value

Anyone have any idea about this issue?

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: php version is 5.6.24

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the reindex command as the same user webserver is running (NOT as a root user or sudo). I was able to reproduce the issue only using root account and never on www-data.

As a context seems you're hit by this bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5146 or https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5900
There is a patch attached, please see if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Having long "url Key"s for categoríes could be the problem too.

When urls are built in Mage_Catalog_Model_Url, the method getUnusedPathByUrlKey is called recusrively when $urlKey is not found in the $requestPath.

If any $requestPath has more than 240 characters it could end up in an infinite recursion loop.  Even if any of the categories has "url Key" value with more than 240 chars, $requestPath could still reach 240 characters because in some iteration it would be the concatenation of current and all parent categories' "url Key" value.